# Return of sizeof()

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "hello";
    printf("str = %s, %ld %ld\n",arr, sizeof(arr), sizeof(*arr) );

    return 0;
}
```

The above program returns: `str = hello, 6 1`

whereas,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *arr = "hello";
    printf("str = %s, %ld %ld\n",arr, sizeof(arr), sizeof(*arr) );

    return 0;
}
```

this program returns `str = hello, 8 1`

Why the returns of sizeof(arr) is different in these two cases?

Comment: In first case it's array, in the second one it's a pointer.

Comment: Because they're different things?

Comment: How it is returning 8?

Comment: Pointer is 8 byte long on your platform...

Comment: Yeah I get it now. Thanks!